# Magento2 Invoice Print PDF editing

Tags: magento2, sales, invoice-pdf

I wan to edit the totals of Invoice print in PDF format. If it was HTML page than its easy to inspect it. But I can't find where i can adjust the widht of a cell.

As you can see the Discount text is overlapping. The file involved in printing is this.
[image]

And here the code of my printing php file

app/code/Catwalk/InvoicePdf/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInv.php

```
 <?php

namespace Catwalk\InvoicePdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice;

class DefaultInv extends DefaultInvoice
{
    protected $product;
    protected $_assetRepo;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $dirctory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        Product $_product,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \ Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList  $dirctory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null, \
        Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->product = $_product;
        $this->dirctory = $dirctory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $taxData, $filesystem, $filterManager, $string, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Draw item line
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $pdf = $this->getPdf();
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];

        $productImage = $this->getProductImage($item, $page);
        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $productImage,
            'is_image'  => 1,
            'feed'  => 210
        );
        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed' => 290,
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 355;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 160;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => 465,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = [
                    'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35,
                ];

                if ($option['value']) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true],1);
        $this->setPage($page);
    }

    /*
    * Return Value of custom attribute
    * */
    private function getProductImage($item,  &$page)
    {
        $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId();
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);
        $image = $product->getSmallImage();
        $filePath = null;
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (!is_null($image) && $extension !== "gif") {
            $imagePath = '/catalog/product'.$image;
            $media = $this->dirctory->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $filePath = $media.$imagePath;
            if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
                $filePath = $this->getProductPlaceholderPath();
            }
        } else {
            $filePath = $this->getProductPlaceholderPath();
        }

        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
           return null;
        }

        return $filePath;
    }
    public function getProductPlaceholderPath()
    {
        $placeholderPath = $this->_assetRepo->createAsset('Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg')->getPath();
        $staticPath = $this->dirctory->getPath('static');
        return $staticPath . '/' . $placeholderPath;
    }
}
```

line 77

```
 $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
```

I want to give more width to this total section, to adjust bigger text values
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your totals are left aligned, which is the issue here. When you change them to right alignment (which is default for Magento 2.4.5-p1) it will fix your problem.

In order to change the totals you have to overwrite `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf::insertTotals` so in case of an invoice you will have to overwrite `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` via preference.

In your new class extend `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` and add the method `insertTotals`:

```php
    /**
     * Insert totals to pdf page
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param  \Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel $source
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    protected function insertTotals($page, $source)
    {
        $order = $source->getOrder();
        $totals = $this->_getTotalsList();
        $lineBlock = ['lines' => [], 'height' => 15];
        foreach ($totals as $total) {
            $total->setOrder($order)->setSource($source);

            if ($total->canDisplay()) {
                $total->setFontSize(10);
                foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
                    $lineBlock['lines'][] = [
                        [
                            'text' => $totalData['label'],
                            'feed' => 475, // you can decrease the offset to increase the width
                            'align' => 'right', // this will fix your issue
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font' => 'bold',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text' => $totalData['amount'],
                            'feed' => 565,
                            'align' => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font' => 'bold'
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        $this->y -= 20;
        $page = $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock]);
        return $page;
    }
```

You can see the `'align'` key within the array, you can change it as you need.

If you want to keep the left alignment you have the option to change the value for the `'feed'` key, which defines the x offset of the text. You must decrease the value to increase the width of the "column".

I made some screenshots to show you the differences:
**feed=475, align=left which is your case**
[image: align_left]

**feed=475, align=right**
[image: align_right]

**feed=400, align=left**
[image: align_left_with_decreased_offset]

Generally I would recommend using the right alignment because then you are not bound by the length of the label. If you keep align left and your label length increases you will run into the same problem again.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to give more width to this total section, to adjust bigger text labels.

Comment: Oups didn't saw this answer Sry Daniel.

Comment: Hi @SanaullahAhmad, this should answer your question already but I made some improvements to clarify how it works.

Comment: Thank @Daniel yes its working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the method `drawLineBlocks` you will see she is called in `AbstractPdf` this class has two properties which are x and y so if you want to change their values you need to extends these methods from AbstractPdf...but it's quite annoying to do as kinda all objects like page have their own x and y. You can check methods like `insertOrder` in that class where you can see how it's really done

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with a completely different answer to everyone else, honestly I don't know why the invoice rendering system in Magento 2 is still so antiquated. I had to customise the invoice for a client recently and I decided to install `eadesignro/module-pdfgenerator` from https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2. Normally I hate installing using anything other than composer packages but this did just what I needed.

Some issues however:

- I could not install it using composer in Magento Commerce (certainly you will also encounter with open-source edition) 2.4.5-p1 as we are running on php 8.1 so installed in `app/code`,
- The html-to-pdf library (mpdf/mpdf) was causing issue so I replaced with `dompdf/dompdf ^2.0`.

I updated `Eadesigndev\Pdfgenerator\Helper::eaPDFSettings()` to look like:

```
$oldErrorReporting = error_reporting();

$pdf = new Dompdf(['is_remote_enabled' => true]);
// When developing locally we use a self-signed cert and need to disable the security checks
if ($this->appState->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
    $context = stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
           'allow_self_signed'=> true,
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ]
    ]);
    $pdf->setHttpContext($context);
}
//@codingStandardsIgnoreLine
$pdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($parts['body']));
$pdf->render();
$pdfToOutput = $pdf->output();

error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);

return $pdfToOutput;
```

NOTE: Only use `is_remote_enabled` can open vulnerabilities if risks are not correctly managed. (audit admin user account, set ACL permissions correctly, etc). I also set the `ssl` values due to local testing and as you can see this is bypassed in prod mode for security reasons.
I also added `use Magento\Framework\App\State` to my __construct() and added `Dompdf\Dompdf` to my includes.

The module essentially allows you to use the email template format in M2 for generating PDF invoices.

Hope it helps.

*If this is the correct answer please mark it "accepted" as it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find the answer.*